# I downloaded TeXLive and ran installation part way through windows says perl stopped

Tags: texlive, texlive-2017

I tried to download and install TeXLive on Windows 7  partway through
Windows says perl has stopped. I have gone though download and install
several times.  It always says perl has stopped.  Any advice?

Comment: have you tried using `install-tl-advanced.bat`? That I usually my goto instead of the `install-tl-windows`. Unless you need to just leave the default settings and hit install.

Comment: Have you any spaces in the installation path? (e.g. in `program files`). Sometimes I had problems with spaces in paths.

Answer (score 1):

Run `install-tl-windows.exe` in Compatibility Mode:

1. Right click on the `install-tl-windows.exe` file.
2. Click on `Properties`.
3. Click on the `Compatibility` tab.
4. Check the `Run this program in compatibility mode` for box.
5. Click on the drop down menu arrow and select `Windows XP`.
6. Click on `OK` to apply the changes.
7. Right click on the `install-tl-windows.exe` file.
8. Click on `Run as Administrator`.

This way works for me on Windows7.